# Why isn't my _gl Google Analytics 4 cross-domain measurement cookie being passed?

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, squarespace, google-analytics-4, gtag.js

I have a Squarespace website with a Booqable checkout which is embedded using JavaScript.

I want Google Analytics 4 to maintain the same cookie for a customer when they enter on Squarespace, then checkout on Booqable. I followed this link which says that cross-domain measurement is the way to go - https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10071811?hl=en.

Standard Google analytics works for the Squarespace site, but cross-domain tracking does not - when I go from Squarespace > Booqable, there is no _gl or _ga (cookie) values in the website URL as suggested in the article linked above.

However:

- When we go from Booqable > Squarespace we do get the _gl & _ga values.
- If we then go from Squarespace back to Booqable, the _gl & _ga values persist.

Yes I'm aware that the article linked above says Javascript can interfere with cross-domain measurement, but that doesn't stop me needing a resolution.

I've tried:

- Going in each direction of site to site as mentioned above
- Adding a button on the Squarespace website and navigating via that rather than the embedded Javascript - this did create the _gl component in the URL as expected, but isn't the solution I need
- The manual setup as outlined here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10071811?hl=en#zippy=%2Cmanual-setup - though if I was doing this part correctly and couldn't find any good documentation or guide on the exact syntax to use and placements within each website

Has anyone been successful setting up something similar? Or have any suggestions on what to do next?

Comment: The manual example shows the usage of gtag set. It's misleading. Better to use gtag  config if you're in the gtag world rather than GTM. Besides, rather than setting config with gtag, you may consider just manually adding the client and session ids to the destination url wherever the navigation is done via a JS redirect rather than normal link click.

Comment: @BNazaruk good point. Thanks for the reply. Is this possible when using embedded Javascript to generate a component on my website? I don't have access to the destination URL, the only thing I get is this code:

<script>
  var booqableOptions = {
    company: '<COMPANY>'
  };
</script>
<script src="<URL>/booqable.js"></script>

Comment: That should only load the library and define some globals. How does the element itself look? Any iframes?

Comment: @BNazaruk It's not in an iframe, it's just a bunch of nested <div> elements including a button that looks like this for the checkout (which redirects to the second site): <a href="#" class="bq-branded bq-button bq-enabled">Checkout</a>